# Resolve library conflict in SML/NJ Compilation Manager

Tags: sml, smlnj, cm

I'm using SML/NJ 110.79, which includes support for new structures defined by the Successor ML project. Among others, the [`Fn`](https://github.com/SMLFamily/BasisLibrary/wiki/2015-005-Addition-of-Fn-module) structure.

As it happens, I already had an identically named structure in one of [my personal project with utilities](https://github.com/igstan/sml-extras), which worked fine before 110.79.

With 110.79, for this *.cm* file:

```
group is
  $/basis.cm
  $SMACKAGE/sml-extras/v0.1.0/sources.sml.cm
```

I get the following error, though:

> sources.cm:3.3-3.45 Error: structure Fn imported from
>   $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm@155252(fn.sml) and also from
>   $SMACKAGE/sml-extras/v0.1.0/(sources.sml.cm):src/fn.sml

Does anyone know how to resolve this conflict through the Compilation Manager. Ideally, my `Fn` structure will be able to "extend" the standard `Fn` by just `open`-ing it, but projects using the sml-extras library, will not see the standard `Fn` structure, only my extended version.

Is this possible? Do I need to wrap/re-export the whole basis.cm library in my sml-extras.cm project?

Comment: Interesting question. The easiest workaround would be to change the name of your version of `Fn` (e.g. to `Fnct`). The Compilation Manager does have facilities for conditional compilation. Also -- the release notes for the new version give a couple of suggestions about how to handle cases where the new features break old code.

Comment: @JohnColeman renaming the structure is my last option :) Momentarily, I've changed to using $/basis-2004.cm, instead of the new one, just to get the code to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using what I believe is called an *administrative* library in the [CM manual](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/CM/new.pdf), §2.9.

What that means precisely is to create an auxiliary *.cm* file that wraps the basis library and re-exports only the symbols we're interested in.

#### sources.cm

This is the main project file.

```
library
  structure Main
is
  (* Let's say this library redefines the Fn and Ref structures    *)
  (* and the REF signature.                                        *)
  $SMACKAGE/sml-extras/v0.1.0/sources.sml.cm

  (* This excludes out Fn, Ref and REF from the Basis library, but *)
  (* imports anything else.                                        *)
  amended-basis.cm

  main.sml
```

#### amended-basis.cm

This file imports `$/basis.cm` and then re-exports all of it except `Fn`, `Ref` and `REF`.

```
group
  library($/basis.cm) - (
    structure Fn
    structure Ref
    signature REF
  )
is
  $/basis.cm
```

#### main.sml

```
structure Main =
  struct
    open Fn (* sml-extras's Fn *)
  end
```

The solution is based on the *set calculus* described in the CM manual, §4 and on the EBNF grammar from Appendix A.

Another solution would have been to change sml-extras to re-export the whole `$/basis.cm`, while shadowing the conflicting symbols. However, in the interest of modularity I decided to go with the solution detailed above.