# How to correctly import modules from a file?

Tags: sml, smlnj

My question has 3 parts:

1. Given a file `.sig` with a signature, how to import it correctly into a file `.sml` specifying a structure implementation?
2. Given a file `.sml` specifying a structure implementation, how to correctly import it into other `.sml` files?
3. Where can I find more information on structuring SML projects? Simple websearch didn't help.

I was told that `open SomeStructure` is not a safe way. I am new to ML-family idioms, hence the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally found this example, which is about module management in the SML project: 
[How to import from another file in SML, with a path relative to the importer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595106/how-to-import-from-another-file-in-sml-with-a-path-relative-to-the-importer)